# Undo function using CRUD

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2

I am making a CRUD application but I need a request to undo the last POST sent

my idea was save each post in a list (Obj stack, which I must use, was a request from the teacher)

delete everything in the repository
remove the last item from stackObj and save the rest to the repository

```
   @PostMapping("/undo")
    public ResponseEntity undoPost() {
        List<Tickets> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
        if (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            for (int i = 0; stack.isEmpty(); i++) {
                tickets.add(stackObj.pop()); //take the last item from the list
            }
            ingressoRepository.saveAll(tickets);
            return ResponseEntity.status(200).build();
        }else{
        return ResponseEntity.status(404).body("Nothing can be undone");
        }
    }
```

But the repository doesn't even save my list

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [Hibernate Envers](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/).
It works both with Hibernate and JPA.

> The Envers module aims to provide an easy auditing / versioning
> solution for entity classes.